# Url con punto "." en Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-models, djangorestframework, django-urls

Tengo el siguiente modelo con `primary_key=True` especificado

```
classTeam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    ... other fields
```

Mi serializador es el siguiente:

```
classTeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   classMeta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('url', 'name',) # and another fields
```

Mi `urls.py`

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'teams', TeamViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),

    # I am not sure if this url is right. I repeat of include(router.urls)
    url(r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w.]+)/', include(router.urls)),

    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Entonces, cuando creo un objeto Team con el atributo name conteniendo un punto . por ejemplo Latinos F.C. , voy al url rest y obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como una alternativa, veo que existe el atributo `lookup_value_regex`. NO estoy seguir de como utilizarlo.

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966110/2773461) es utilizado con una expresión regular básica , pero si yo la uso, cualquier objeto Team no es accesado por la url rest

¿Cómo puedo obtener una url del tipo `/api/teams/Name F.C.` en mi modelo serializado `Team`?

Comment: Un poco tarde, pero lo primero que veo inmediatamente es que no estás permitiendo espacios en `[-\w.]+` ... Si aún estás con este problema, ¿podrías probar con `r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w. ]+)/?$'` (sólo agregando un espacio en la clase de caracteres)? ... Aunque dudo si no son codificados como `%20`, por lo que también probaría con `r'^api/teams/(?P<name>[-\w.]+(?:%20[-\w.]+)*)/?$'`

Comment: @Mariano tu respuesta ha sido acertada. Primero que todo, disculpas por responder tambien tarde a tu sugerencia, dado que andaba con mi atención centrada en otros proyectos y no habia sacado tiempo para probar lo que me comentas. Lo probé y con cualquiera de las dos `URLs` que me ilustras en tu comentario puedo crear un registro de un `Team` con un punto '`.`' Lo que me sucede es que ahora no puedo crear un registro de un `Team` con espacios o nombre compuesto

Comment: @Mariano cuando creo un registro con un nombre compuesto me sale el siguiente error `raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "team-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the lookup_field attribute on this field.
[03/May/2017 00:39:56] "POST /api/teams/ HTTP/1.1" 500 173266`

Comment: @Mariano Sin embargo a pesar de que tengo este problema del espacio en blanco para que sea permitido tu sugerencia me permite poner el url con caracter punto, asi que si lo pones como solución, puedo validarla como aceptada.